# Как проверить значение на ноль php

Tags: php, null

Добрый день никак не могу понять почему код неправильно работает. Значение переменной $data['brand'] может иметь три значения(0, любое число и new). Не могу проверить на ноль. Скажите где ошибка пожалуйста.

```
if (!(int) $data['brand'] or $data['brand'] == 0) {
    //print_r("прошел brand ... <br />".$data['brand']);

    if (/* $data['brand'] != "" and (int) */$data['brand'] <= 0) {

        print_r("прошел brand ... <br />".$data['brand']);

    } else {

        print_r("прошел brand new <br />".$data['brand']);  

    }

} else {

    print_r("прошел brand установлен <br />".$data['brand']);

}
```

Comment: Покажите строчку где массив $data создаётся и заполняется. У меня ваш код нормально работает(если добавить в самый верх 
 $data['brand'] = 0; )

Comment: Переменная числовая или строковая?

Comment: значение берется из селекта методом post. в зависимости от выбранного значения переменная может меняться на 0, любое число, пустое значение(если пустое то можно было бы использовать такое же условие как и для 0)  и текстовое значение.

Comment: @МаксимСычевский тогда убедитесь точно в том, что $data не пуста, например так : print_r($data);

Comment: @Максим Сычевский так проверяете всё же на 0 или null ?